# Can we use identity broker such as ADFS to login to multiple portals, we will be using IAM as Identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-iam, identity, provider, broker

Can we use identity broker such as ADFS to login to multiple portals, we will be using IAM as Identity provider, so once user logins to one portal through this setup he doesn't need to login separately to other portals

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.